# Issue in generating private key

Tags: java, key, private-key, key-pair

Private key generation

```
          public PrivateKey getStoredPrivateKey(String filePath) {
    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    byte[] keydata = getKeyData(filePath);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec encodedPrivateKey = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keydata);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = null;
    try {
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("hello");
        privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(encodedPrivateKey);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return privateKey;
}
```

I am using it here

```
  PrivateKey privateKey = new KryptoUtil().getStoredPrivateKey(privateKeyFilePath);
```

but its showing error

```
    hello
    java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:                          
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     03
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
```

I am passing a (.p12) file in getStoredPrivateKey(String filePath) function.

why its giving error?

Comment: Are you sure your private key is of spec PKCS#8. Try with other spec like RSAPrivateKeySpec

Comment: how can I identify that its not PKCS#8

Answer (score 1):

P12 is is keystore type where multiple keys and certificates can be stored and a password can be used to protect them. You can search about P12 (PKCS12) on Internet. Your file is P12 file, so most likely it is PKCS12 format file.

To get private key from P12 file use below code. You need below things before calling this code.

> **filePath**. String path (absolute) of P12 file.
>
> **filePassword**. It is a char[]. Represents password of p12 file.
>
> **keyPassword**. It is a char[]. Represents password for private key. Most
>   likely it is same as filePassword.
>
> **alias**. A String. Represents by which alias a private key stored in P12
>   archive/keystore.

To check what is the alias of your private key you can use below command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <yourfile>.p12 -storetype pkcs12
```

It will ask for password then print multiple lines. Look for

```
Entry Type: PrivatKeyEntry
```

There you will find the alias.

Initialize these variables and then use below code to get private key. You can also get Certificates/Public key associate with this key. Look for API of PrivateKeyEntry

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(filePath), filePassword);
PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyPassword));
PrivateKey key = privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
```